# Hair color probability

Tags: probability

50% of the population have the hair colour gold, 40% have brown hair and 10% have black hair.

Select 10 people randomly on the street.  What is the probability that there are 5 people who have gold hair and 4 people who have have brown hair and 1 person who has black hair?

My guess is $ \binom{10}{5}(0.5)^5 \binom{5}{4}(0.4)^4 \binom{1}{1}(0.1)^1=0.1008$, however I don't know if it is correct, what I know so far is that the order of selection and the combinations should be considered, like $(0.5)^5(0.4)^4(0.1)^1$ is obviously wrong, because we may, but how to deal with probability and combinations at the same time?

Comment: This type of distribution is also described in [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution). The PMF or probability mass function there gives the required probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct. First, there are $\binom{10}{5}$ ways that you may get 5 people with golden hair from 10. Now there are $10-5=5$ left, and there are $\binom{5}{4}$ ways to have four people with brown hair in the remaining 5. Then you have 1 left with only 1 choice. Finally you multiply the probabilities for each case.
$$\binom{10}{5}(0.5)^5 \binom{5}{4}(0.4)^4 \binom{1}{1}(0.1)^1=\frac{10!}{5!~4!~1!}(0.5)^5(0.4)^4(0.1)^1=0.1008$$

Comment: Did the question get edited or changed after this answer was supplied? The above refers to seats and the question refers to hair colour.

Comment: I edited, it is not changed, maybe my words make you confused, sorry!

Comment: This answer seems to be phrased wrongly, it says "you choose 5 people from 10", but that is not what is happening. There are $10\choose 5$ orderings that we may get exactly five people with gold hair, but there is no choice of 5 people at all anywhere in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Now I have a another question, if we look at the term $\binom{10}{5}(0.5)^5=7.85$, 7.85 is but greater than 1, this means the probability of that if we choose 5 people out of 10 people and 5 of them have gold hair? How should I understand this very term?

Comment: yes, 5 people means 5 golden hair @SuzuHirose

Comment: @IchbinAuslander you are not choosing people at all.

Comment: @MathFail No, you are not choosing 5 people, that is not what the question says. It says that what is the probability of getting 5 gold hair people if you choose 10 people at random.

Comment: right, so that's why I wrote seat initially, but you said seat makes you confused, so I changed to people @SuzuHirose

Comment: I'm not confused, the answer is wrong.

Comment: Why it is wrong, it is multinomial @SuzuHirose

Answer (score 3):

If you are confused by combinatoric problems, it is a good idea to pick a simpler problem, say there are only two hair colours, gold and brown, then there is $2/3$ probability of gold, and we ask for three people, then you may have
$$
\begin{align}
p(GGG)&=(2/3)^3\\
p(GGB)&=(2/3)^2\times 1/3\\
p(GBG)&=2/3\times 1/3\times 2/3\\
p(GBB)&=2/3\times (1/3)^2\\
p(BGG)&=1/3\times(2/3)^2\\
p(BGB)&=1/3\times 2/3\times 1/3\\
p(BBG)&=(1/3)^3\times 2/3\\
p(BBB)&=(1/3)^3\\
\end{align}
$$
so the probability of GGB, say, in any order, is $3\times(2/3)^2\times 1/3$. It's difficult to build intuition if the numbers are big and there are extra complicating factors, so it's better to do easy problems first.

Comment: what you wrote here is to select the seat, because your order is the seat, so what's wrong? you choose 3B to put into 3 seats, so the coefficient is $\binom{3}{3}$, if you put 2B into 3 seats, the coefficients is $\binom{3}{2}$, which is BBG, BGB, GBB